# Why does $.getJSON reverse the response list?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have the following code:

```
// Setup a content array for the tooltips
var Data = [];
var search = $("input#field_search").val();
var combo = $("select#search_option").val();
var jsonUrl = "ajax.php?module=formation&action=get_participant_list_json&filter_by=" + combo + "&search=" + search;

$.getJSON(jsonUrl, function(data) {
    var items = [];
    alert(data.join(" || " )); //WHAT TO SHOW YOU HERE

    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        //alert(val);
        items.push(val.replace(/@/gi, "#"));
    });
    //console.log(items);
    //alert(items.join(" || " ));
    $(".tips").each(function(i) {
        $(this).simpletip({ content: items[i] });
    });
});
```

If I access

`ajax.php?module=formation&action=get_participant_list_json`

or

`ajax.php?module=formation&action=get_participant_list_json&filter_by=&search=`

directly with IE7, I get the good response data in the following order:

```
["0Bequart Claire","1AZZI Sarah"]
```

But if I `alert(data.join(" || " ));` I got reversed

```
  0AZZI Sarah || 1Bequart Claire
```

Do you know where my mistake is? Why is the response list in reverse order?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You should access the complete URL instead, that URL seems just like half of it

Comment: why? but I still got the same if ajax.php?module=formation&action=get_participant_list_json&filter_by=&search=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot completely follow your code so I apologise if I have misunderstood, but .push looks like an operation intended to implement a LIFO stack.  If you want to unload (list) the array in the same order that you loaded it, you should load it with an append operation and unload it with an iterator.

Comment: alert(data.join(" || " )); I did not do any push yet just alert